# Smarty 2 in 1 variable

Tags: php, variables, smarty

How can i put in variable 'A', variable 'B'

I have two variable `{$current_page}` and `{$globalContent.INDEX_BTN}`

How can i make something like that -> `{$globalContent.{$current_page}_BTN}` that word INDEX in variable `{$globalContent.INDEX_BTN}` will switched to value from variable `{$current_page}`

Edited:
I want to do in Smarty, something like this what i can do in PHP

```
    $lang = array with text
    $curr_page = 'ORDER';
    echo $lang[$curr_page.'_BTN'];
```

P.S variable `$lang` it's array with many indexes which contain text, and two of them `INDEX_BTN & ORDER_BTN`, so can i make something like that PHP code in Smarty ? That array lang assigned to Smarty like `{$globalContent}`

Comment: I can't find a related question here on SO, but [this may be useful to you](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=77965&sid=54c59bc6a21774c39da21b55dcc1b569)

Comment: I edited post, wrote how it looks in PHP, and that i want do that in Smarty. Is it real ?

Comment: Is it real to do somethink like that in Smarty ?

Comment: Yes, as in the forum topic I linked. I don't have direct experience with this and therefore am not going to post an answer, but something like `{ assign var="btn_var" value="\`$current_page\`_BTN" }` used as  
`{ $globalContent.$btn_var }`

Comment: Perfect, it's what i needed, sorry that inattentively was reading topics from your link. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
{assign var="page_index" value=join('',array($current_page,'_BTN'))}

{$global_content.$page_index}
```